# How to split output by timepoint in long format time-series data?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, missing-data

I would like to use gg_miss_var() from the `naniar` package to look at the amount of missing data at each timepoint in my data frame. The data frame includes time-series data in long format.

I have code that works with the df overall (see #1 in **Code** below). How can I extend this to produce the output split by *Timepoint* (see #2 in **Code** below for my attempted code)?

To clarify, what I would like to do is essentially repeat #1 in **Code** using data from each timepoint (per the *Timepoint* variable). Therefore, the amount of missing data for each variable would be presented for baseline data, year1 data, and year2 data, separately. Currently, #1 in **Code** looks at the missing data for all timepoints (i.e., baseline, year1, year2) combined.

I will be doing further analyses split by *Timepoint* with this data df, for example regressions, and so would ideally like code that is easily manipulated for these purposes.

Below is an example data frame (see **Example Data**). Note that the data frame I am working with is much larger (i.e., N = ~21,900)

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(naniar) # for gg_miss_var()

# 1. All missing data
gg_miss_var(df[,c("Score.1","Score.2","Score.3","Score.4")]) 

# 2. Missing data split by timepoint [does not work]
df %>% 
  group_by(Timepoint) %>% 
  gg_miss_var(.[,c("Score.1","Score.2","Score.3","Score.4")]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Example Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L),  Timepoint = c("baseline", "year1", "year2", 
"baseline", "year1", "baseline"), Score.1 = c(NA, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5), Score.2 = c(11, 
10, 8, 8, 8, 9), Score.3 = c(4, NA, 9, 10, 8, 6), Score.4 = c(22, 
50, 33, 28, 27, 33)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Example Output**

The below is the output produced for #1 in **Code**. What I would like is copies of the below, using only data from the corresponding timepoint (i.e., baseline, year1, year2).

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "split?"  If you have the same number of each Timepoint class `{baseline, year1, yeare2}`, you could `pivot_wider` on that column and get a separate column for each class. If you want to analyze each Timepoint class separately, you could make separate data sets using `filter`. Can you give an example of what you want to ultimately do?

Comment: Please add the package used since `gg_miss_var` isn't as far as I know a base R function.

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect it?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(naniar)
df %>% select(-ID) %>% 
  group_by(Timepoint) %>% 
  gg_miss_var(facet = Timepoint)
```

[image]

Unless you prefer three separate plots. Then do this:

```
df %>% select(-ID) %>% 
  group_by(Timepoint) %>% 
  group_map(~gg_miss_var(.x)+ggtitle(.y))
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this the effect you were expecting?